# eteor: maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: meteor, max, call

What I've to change to ignore the error? I installed 1.8 meteor using Choco?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I just rename my another node-modules folder to node-modulesold and now it's working fine. The directory is C:\Users\Durjoy\node_modules_old